# Install program on Windows without messing the registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I'd like to install a program that I'll use only once. If I do it on Windows system the program will leave a lot of rubbish in registry and probably some user files that I don't want to take care after. Is there a way to install it in some kind of sandbox, where it won't mess with my registry or leave any files behind?

I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Use a Virtual Machine and when you are done, just erase it

Comment: Your worried about adding something to the registry except that most applications not only write nothing to the registry but adding to the registry isn't an actual performance concern

Comment: What program are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual machine using VirtualBox. On that machine you need to install your desired OS, and then install the required software. The virtual machine can be deleted after you're done with it.

Comment: True, but I would need another Windows copy. Is it legal and possible to have same key both on host and guest machine?

Comment: You can install Windows without serial/activation if this is a one-time task, and then delete the VM.